# Using ArcGIS Desktop to find data folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am taking a GIS certification course on Courseera. I downloaded the ArcGIS for desktop 10.3.1. I am trying to work with ArcMap. I created a GIS folder on my desktop and followed the steps -given to me by my course instructor, to connect the folder to ArcMap. Once I do that, there is supposed to be an "IntroductionToArcM[image]ap" data folder that pops up. The folder does not pop up. I have uploaded the image below of what my screen is supposed to look like. The folder does not pop up.

Has anyone had this same issue?

Is there something that I need to do different or is it the software itself?

Comment: Can you find the "IntroductionToArcMap" directory using Windows Explorer?

Comment: Did you download data from Coursera or were there directions to download data from somewhere? There is no folder like this if you just install ArcGIS Desktop. It might be part of the Tutorial setup.

Comment: You likely need to right-click the directory in arccatalog and refresh.

Comment: Thank you to the above inputs. I am still trying to figure this thing out. I am going to have to give Esri a call tomorrow.